# REST API Call in Python returns Error Code 500011

Tags: python, rest, azure-purview

When I make this REST API call in Postman it comes back with an access token
[image]
When I attempt it in Python using this code, I get [this error](https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=500011)

```
import os
import requests
import json
import jmespath
import pandas as pd

from pprint import pprint
from pyapacheatlas.auth import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
from pyapacheatlas.core import PurviewClient, AtlasEntity, AtlasProcess, TypeCategory
from pyapacheatlas.core.typedef import *

from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

tenant_id = "tenant-id"
client_id = "client-id"
client_secret = "client-secret"
data_catalog_name = "catalog-name"



url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token"
payload= f'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&resource={resource_url}'
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}


response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
access_token = json.loads(response.text) #['access_token']

print(access_token)
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I see ten headers in the postman request and only one (explicit) in your code. Can you show the requests that are sent from postman?

Comment: Try to pass the url parameters via the params dictionary of requests.get instead of part of the url